# How can I use the Randomforest classifier in python to train data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, training-data

Following code I used to train the model with the Randomforest classifier:

````
model = Pipeline([('vectorizer', tvec),('classifier', clf)])

model.fit(IV_train, DV_train)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    predictions = model.predict(IV_test)
    confusion_matrix(predictions, DV_test) ```
````

However, I received following error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-122-6ea0987e0222>", line 7
    predictions = model.predict(IV_test)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your code has indentation problem which means extra unnecessary spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered this error because you have given indentation(i.e added tab or used space) to line 7 and line 8 even though it was not needed.

You might want to use it like this (as you can see there's no indentation or spacing here)

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
predictions = model.predict(IV_test)
confusion_matrix(predictions, DV_test)
```

Check out [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/), It gives a really good idea about indentation in python

Comment: Thank you for your comment I was able to solve the problem :)